# MS-Mpi Works but MPI.NET does not working, App showing Blank screen

Tags: c#, mpi

A) I had set up:

1. A Windows server 2008 r2 (192.168.6.10) with domain (OFFICE) and a user "majid"
2. And 2 nodes : 192.168.6.164, 192.168.6.154 (all Win8 x64)  joined on domain (OFFICE) with user "majid"

B) and also installed:

1. "HPC Pack 2008 R2 Client Utilities Redistributable Package with Service Pack 4" (HpcClient_x64.msi) on all three machines
2. "HPC Pack 2008 R2 MS-MPI Redistributable Package with Service Pack 4" (mpi_x64.exe) on all three machines
3. "HPC Pack 2008 R2 SDK with Service Pack 4" (sdk_x64.msi) on my developer machine (192.168.6.154) for building MPI enabled programs
4. And copied pingpong.exe (c++) and pingpong_.exe (C#) on location C:\MPI\ of all machines

C) and the way that I run pingpong.exe is:

1. running on all machines this command via CMD or PowerShell by Admin, and after that entering password for  user "majid": (after that, smpd will pop up with blank screen, FINE!)
   runas  /user:OFFICE\majid "C:\Program Files\Microsoft HPC Pack 2008 R2\Bin\smpd.exe -d"
2. Running on my Developer machine this command via CMD or PowerShell by Admin , and after that entering password for  user "majid": ( I want to run pingpong.exe in real cluster network)
   runas  /user:OFFICE\majid "cmd /K mpiexec -hosts 2 192.168.6.154 1 192.168.6.164 1 C:\mpi\pingpong.exe"
3. The result is GOOD! And my ping pong working!

*** PROBLEM:
pinpong.exe is a program that written in c++ (I think) so there is no problem and my cluster works!
I want to run pingpong_.exe that is written in C# with MPI.NET SDK , but after below set up it still won't work!

I have installed:

1. "MPI.NET Runtime.msi" on all machines!
2. "MPI.NET SDK.msi" on my developer machine (192.168.6.154)
3. reset the systems and ran all steps in (C) with pingpong_.exe

but result is blank screen! (my pinpong_.exe shows nothing!) if again i repeat steps with pingpong.exe it is working!
note: I also could run pingpong_.exe with "mpiexec -n 2 pingpong_.exe" on every machine, and it is working! that means it works with it self! but in network noooo!
note2: I disabled firewall on all machines!
please help me how to get pingpong_.exe (c# codded app) working in MS-MPI enabled Cluster ?
after that I want to write my own app with C# and run it in cluster for 
University Project!

I couldn't simplified it more.
Thanks for Your Attention

updated: -----
I Got response from pingpong_.exe (c#) after 2+ minutes (about 135 seconds) so actually it is working but why 2 min lags????

Is it MPI.NET problem? or pingpong_.exe ?

note: pingpong_.exe is renamed pure app that i found in MPI.net samples located : "C:\Program Files (x86)\MPI.NET\pingpong.exe"

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what the issue is, but either way, I haven't seen a lot of MS-MPI experts around here. You might have better luck if you contact their support team directly. They have information on their website: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524831(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thanks for reply, i'll send an email to their team